# page refresh not happening when I am changing the URL from the URL bar : AngularJS 1

Tags: angularjs, page-refresh, partial-page-refresh

my base URL :- `http://localhost:8080/App/#/` , let us say I am at 
    `http://localhost:8090/App/#/page1`. Now when I change this URL from the URL bar directly by deleting the `page1` and pressing the enter key, I observed that, in the network section all the controller/directive/service js files does not loads and because of that variables and objects does not gets reset and the application gives inconsistent result.

What I want is when ever user navigates to the base url not just by `$location.path('/')` but also by manipulating the URL from the URL bar page refresh should happen just in the same way when first time we run the application.

How can I achieve this??

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: are you using `ui-router` for routing?

Comment: No I am using ng-route

Comment: Add this to your main App   $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, currentRoute, previousRoute) {
         $route.reload();
        $anchorScroll();
    });

Comment: Browsers ignore url fragments while making a request. So if you change the fragment browser won't try to load a new resource hence no activity in network tab. You have to manually intercept location change and then trigger refresh

Comment: If you have set a route in `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page1')` then it will redirect to page1 even though you removed `/page1` from url.

Comment: put a breakpoint in your routing config and check if you have set proper routing or it is going to default.

Comment: Its going to proper routing , but i want page to be refreshed when its going to base(default) URL from any other URL like /page1, /page2 etc. by directly changing the url in address bar.